# Replacing many std::async calls by a threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I have a programm that calls `std::async` many many times.  The tasks that are executed are reasonable short (like a few hundred miliseconds each).  I figure that there is significant overhead for thread creation and I wonder if I can avoid this somehow.  The code that enumerates the jobs runs much faster than the processing of the jobs.  Therefore I already have a sort of pooling in place.  It goes like this.  I create an array of 'job slots':

```
template <typename T>
struct job {
  std::future <void> fut;
  std::vector <T*> *result;
  bool inUse;
}
```

Before the parallel code starts, I initialize the array of job slots, creating the result vectors only once.  Then everytime the job enumeration code has enumerated a job, it looks for a job slot that is not in use.  If there is a free slot, it will start (with std::async) a new job, move the future to the slot.  The job runs and fills the result vector.  If there is no free slot, then the code checks if any of the futures in the slots is ready.  If so, it processes the result vector, and then uses that slot.  If not, it waits a few miliseconds.  This code runs very nicely, and scales exactly to the number of processors available.  I learned that each call to `std::async` creates a new thread, and indeed, I can see the process IDs scrolling through.  I want to remove this overhead, creating the threads once and for all in the beginning.  How to proceed?

I have found this threadpool implementation 
https://code.google.com/p/cppthreadpool/downloads/list
but it states that a task should take one or two seconds for this to be efficient.  I don't need any fancy scheduling, priorities, etc.  I just want to remove overhead for repeated construction and destruction of threads.

Comment: I ran a test program that creates tasks using std::async and found that many tasks were ran by same thread!! In fact I see 2 threads ran 20 async tasks. So the standard library does thread pooling?

Comment: What OS was this on?  I'm mostly interested in Linux.  How can you be sure that the same thread was used, and not just the same thread ID?

Comment: windows; vs2010; doing wait() on futures at the last.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test program that creates tasks using std::async and found that many tasks were ran by same thread!! In fact I see 2 threads ran 25 async tasks. So looks like the standard library does some thread pooling already.

```
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        auto fut = std::async([]
        {          
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() <<std::endl;
        });
        futures.push_back(std::move(fut));
    }
    std::for_each(futures.begin(), futures.end(), [](std::future<void> & fut)
    {
        fut.wait();
    });
```

Comment: Your standard future call lacks a launch policy.  The runtime implementation may choose to run them all in the main thread.  Can you try with `std::launch::async` please.  I'm on linux and I get 25 different thread IDs.

Comment: I got around 6 threads for 25 tasks with `std::launch::async`. 1:4 thread: tasks ratio you can say

Comment: @MooingDuck When I tried manually using VS in windows it look like tasks are executing in the thread pool. But all the documentation are saying launch::async will create a new thread. Can you share any source(s) to justify "MSVC uses a thread pool, reusing thread" ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async "The template function async runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call." Also, Your own tests prove it